# SSH Windows to UNIX

Tags: windows, unix, shell, ssh

I built a batch file from my windows machine that connects to a UNIX server. I Then want commands to execute in UNIX from the batch file. UNIX doesn't seem to recognize my commands after I am logged into the server. This is what I coded:

ssh SERVERNAME
exit

Right now, I am just trying to make it log in and exit. I get logged into the server, but then the exit command does not execute. Does anyone know to make UNIX execute my commands after I'm logged in using this batch file?

Comment: Your post looks like a one line command `ssh SERVERNAME exit` but your text in edit mode shows two lines. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

`exit` isn't being executed because it isn't a command, it's a shell internal (`which exit` if you don't believe me).  Try `echo hello world` instead.

Comment: This is a good answer and could also be paraphrased as "try basic troubleshooting."

Comment: @innaM see my comment in sharth's Answer.

Comment: `ssh -t server echo hello world` doesnt work for me!? whereas `ssh -t server ls` does!

Answer (score 4):

ssh SERVERNAME 'exit'

you will probably end up with something such as:

```
ssh SERVERNAME 'bash some_remote_script.sh'
```

(replace bash with whatever shell you please)

im not sure why "chaos" keeps getting upvoted, his response has nothing to do whatsoever with the question.  ssh SERVERNAME 'exit' works perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 This worked for me, thanks! (read also my comment to @wr answer)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems to work for me, but try this:

```
ssh -t server command
```

You might just need the pseudo-tty allocated.

Comment: I think it "seems" to work, as `ssh -t server ls` does an `ls` then exits, so `ssh -t server exit` does nothing as @chaos suggest, then the ssh shell exits! @Gerry

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section "7.3 Using Plink in batch files and scripts" at the [plink documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). That might do what you want.

Comment: I've been struggling with plink for this issue, and how thinking that this is looking to work better in this instance. (I normally do use plink for other stuff)

Comment: More specifically, I am trying to run a script which requires user input, but with plink its always non-interactive!?